# Flutter - Is it necessary to use Model class in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, model

Is Model class a must have for flutter application? If so, where is it comes into the picture in a simple database fetch, insert, update scenario? I am using supabase for my application. Can't I fetch data from database table and display in a page (I am using Provider for State Management)? Similarly, can't I insert data by directly reading from widgets?

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessarily a must have and there are always work arounds, however it could save you **a lot** of code because you'll be repeating yourself often without it, especially if you're making a bunch of API calls and you need to serialize the data to a JSON readable format.

If you fetch it from your database I assume it'll be in a JSON format, from which you'll have to deserialize it. Personally, I think your project will be much easier with models classes.

There are plenty of extensions that can help you with this. For example, search for Dart Data Class Generator.

Answer (score 1):

I did my first apps with models but honestly you can totally get away with Maps/Objects.

If you are the only one working on the app, then you can definetly do it without models